# Finding the perpendicular distance from a force to a point

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics

> Find the moment of each force about the point, P, stating whether it is clockwise or anticlockwise.

[image: questions]

I think it's straightforward but I'm not seeing it. How would I find these perpendicular distances? I think that for the first one, it would be $8 sin(30)$ but I can't visually make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am taking force vector in two directions one is perpendicular to the point  P and other is passing through point P.

For the first one, you can write it as $$20*sin(30)*8$$

For the second one, you can write it as $$20*sin(40)*5$$

Comment: How come? Why can you substitute the force vector for distance? Thanks for replying.

Comment: Here I am taking to the components  of force vector one is passing through the point p thus generating no moment but one is perpendicular and passing through a point  that is 8m away from  point p thus perpendicular distance 8m